# aws amplify: How to add user to a auth group when they signup to my app

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amazon-cognito-triggers

I am making a app that requires to scope the users to a specific access level.

For Example there are Three groups

> Admin FUll CRUD

> Teacher Table Specific permissions

> Student Table Specific permissions

While Admin will be created From the Console and that admin will create Teachers accounts.

When anyone signs up to the app I need them to be put in a Students Group by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Amplify CLI when adding the auth category in the default or manual workflow you can setup a lambda trigger to add a user to a cognito group automatically upon signup.

Walk through the options until you reach this step and select `Add User to Group`:

```
$ Do you want to enable any of the following capabilities?
  ❯ ◯ Add Google reCaptcha Challenge
    ◯ Email Verification Link with Redirect
    ◯ Add User to Group
    ◯ Email Domain Filtering (deny list)
    ◯ Email Domain Filtering (allow list)
    ◯ Custom Auth Challenge Flow (basic scaffolding - not for production)
    ◯ Override ID Token Claims
```

See this section of the CLI documentation for more details: [Set up lambda triggers](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/lambda-triggers/#set-up-lambda-triggers)